# Declaration of Issue after upgrading cakephp 1.3 to 2.0

Tags: cakephp, upgrade

I am getting this issue when I try to upgrade from cakephp 1.3 to 2.0

`Strict (2048): Declaration of UserController::validate() should be compatible with Controller::validate() [APP/Controller/UserController.php, line 3]`

My line number 3 in the `UserController.php` is

```
class UserController extends AppController {
```

I have defined a validate() function in side UserController.php and calling like this

$this->validate();

Please help

Comment: You need to provides us with that line of code.... it is something there you did not remove or replace

Comment: Just updated my line number 3. Or do you need the full code of UserController.php ?

Comment: do you have any `validate()` functions defined in `UserController` or `AppController` ?

Comment: Also, it should be `UsersController.php`

Comment: To use CakePHP conventions it should be `class UsersController extends AppController {`. Basically `User` should be `Users`. Unless you are specifically breaking the convention here...

Comment: oh sorry, yes it is UsersController.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `public function validate() {` defined in Cake's `Controller.php`.

If you have your own function, you should rename it.